# How to remove padding (cellpadding) from the <td> element?

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple calculator using HTML, CSS, and JS. My question is how to remove the padding of the  element inside my calculator table.
[Visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJs94.png)

To remove spacing between  elements in HTML, googling suggests adding the attributes `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` to the  element, which I did. It also suggests adding a CSS selector `table { border-collapse: collapse}`. However, border-collapse does not work as I expected: the padding does not get removed, and the table corners become wrecked.

```css
  /* Global CSS */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --calc-bg: rgb(184, 243, 216);
  --btn-bg: rgb(252, 246, 230);
  --active-btn-bg: rgb(106, 200, 153);
  --main-btn-bg: rgb(71, 202, 143);
  --text-color: rgb(45, 53, 44);
  --display-bg: rgb(252, 246, 230);
}


/* Calculator CSS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@900&display=swap');
.calculator {
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  height: 580px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: var(--calc-bg);
  border: solid rgb(45, 52, 42) 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
}

.display-box {
  background-color: var(--display-bg);
  border: solid black 0.5px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
}

#btn {
  background-color: var(--main-btn-bg);
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=button] {
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: var(--btn-bg);
  color: var(--text-color);
  border: solid rgb(45, 52, 42) 2px;
  width: 4rem;
  border-radius: 10%;
  height: 4rem;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px rgb(45, 52, 42);
}

input:active[type=button] {
  background: var(--active-btn-bg);
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
```

````html
<table class="calculator" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr>

    <td colspan="3"> <input class="display-box" type="text" id="result" disabled /> </td>

    <!-- clearScreen() function clears all the values -->

    <td> <input type="button" value="C" onclick="clearScreen()" id="btn" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <!-- display() function displays the value of clicked button -->

    <td> <input type="button" value="1" onclick="display('1')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="2" onclick="display('2')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="3" onclick="display('3')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="/" onclick="display('/')" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td> <input type="button" value="4" onclick="display('4')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="5" onclick="display('5')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="6" onclick="display('6')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="display('-')" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td> <input type="button" value="7" onclick="display('7')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="8" onclick="display('8')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="9" onclick="display('9')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="+" onclick="display('+')" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td> <input type="button" value="." onclick="display('.')" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="0" onclick="display('0')" /> </td>

    <!-- calculate() function evaluates the mathematical expression -->

    <td> <input type="button" value="=" onclick="calculate()" id="btn" /> </td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="*" onclick="display('*')" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>


} ```
````

Comment: You set a width of 500px on your table

Comment: @j08691 thank you, I changed the width to auto and set the width of 25% for every td element inside the tr rows for calculator buttons. The only problem I have now is the padding by the Y-axis, as there is some spacing between the table rows.
I gave the same class for all <tr> except the first one for the display-box and the "Clear" button and tried to experiment with the height % values, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the width and height of the table and its elements, along with using `border-collapse: collapse` and `border-spacing: 0` helped to solve the issue